# How to open a PowerShell in the current folder?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-explorer, powershell

This keyboard shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> opens the command prompt. [Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2009UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx) points to an app that does the same for PowerShell and says it's builtin in Windows 7.

The tool doesn't seem to work on Windows 7 and can't find the builtin option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Elevation PowerToys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.06.elevation.aspx) from Microsoft include a tool to open a PowerShell window in the current folder, among lots of other useful things.  (I'm assuming there's no built-in way to do this, otherwise Microsoft wouldn't offer it as a download on their site.)

Once you've downloaded and extracted them, navigate to their folder, right-click on `PowerShellHere.inf` and click *Install*.  A *PowerShell Prompt Here* option will be added to the context menu of all directories and drives.  You can also add context menu entries to open a PowerShell window with administrator privileges or as the `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` user.

Alternatively, if you don't want to install anything, you can just use the *Open command window here* option built-in to Windows and then run `powershell` at the normal command prompt.  A PowerShell session will open in the same command prompt window.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the blog post you linked to mentioned that he uses the Pscx modules.  The installer for the older version of Pscx added the context menu entries for `Open PowerShell Here`, and it looks like he did not realise that it was the installer that did it.

Pscx no longer uses an installer.

Answer (score 0):

```
New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
if(-not (Test-Path -Path "HKCR:\Directory\shell\$KeyName"))
{
    Try
    {
        New-Item -itemType String "HKCR:\Directory\shell\$KeyName" -value "Open PowerShell in this Folder" -ErrorAction Stop
        New-Item -itemType String "HKCR:\Directory\shell\$KeyName\command" -value "$env:SystemRoot\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location '%V'" -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Host "Successfully!"
     }
     Catch
     {
         Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
     }
}
else
{
    Write-Warning "The specified key name already exists. Type another name and try again."
}
```

You can download detail script from [how to start PowerShell from Windows Explorer](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-start-PowerShell-4953b7ba)